# Calculation not being done right

Tags: c++, calculation

I'm fairly new to c++, I have been given an assignment to do a fairly basic program that users can use to buy tickets but I am having some issues with the calculation.

This is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double type_ticket, num_tickets, price1, price2, price3, total_price, decision;

cout << "Welcome to the ticket kiosk.";
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "1. VVIP - RM 200";
cout << "\n";
cout << "2. VIP - RM 150";
cout << "\n";
cout << "3. Normal - RM 100" << endl;
cout << "\n";


do
{
cout << "Please select the category of ticket you would like to purchase: ";
cin  >> type_ticket;
cout << "\n";


if (type_ticket == 1)
{
cout << "How many would you like: ";
cin  >> num_tickets;
cout << "\n";
price1 = num_tickets * 200;
cout << "The price is: RM " << price1 << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "1. YES" << endl;
cout << "2. NO" << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "Would you like to continue purchasing more tickets: ";
cin  >> decision;
cout << "\n";
}


else if (type_ticket == 2)
{
cout << "How many would you like: ";
cin  >> num_tickets;
cout << "\n";
price2 = num_tickets * 150;
cout << "The price is: RM " << price2 << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "1. YES" << endl;
cout << "2. NO" << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "Would you like to continue purchasing more tickets: ";
cin  >> decision;
cout << "\n";
}


else if (type_ticket == 3)
{
cout << "How many would you like: ";
cin  >> num_tickets;
cout << "\n";
price3 = num_tickets * 100;
cout << "The price is: RM " << price3 << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
cout << "1. YES" << endl;
cout << "2. NO" << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "Would you like to continue purchasing more tickets: ";
cin  >> decision;
cout << "\n";
}


else
{
cout << "You have entered an invalid input, please try again. " << endl;
cout << "\n";
}


}
while (decision == 1);

total_price = price1 + price2 + price3;
cout << "The grand total is: RM " << total_price << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "Thank you for using this service today, we hope you enjoy the show." << endl;
cout << "\n";

}
```

The problem that I am having is when the user buys tickets from vvip and/or vip, the calculation for total_price is not being done right. When a price 3 has been entered however, the calculation works fine.

User buys vvip and/or vip = calculation not done right.
User buys normal and vvip and/or vip = calculation done right.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

FYI, this code is not yet complete, but for now, this is what I have.

Comment: please explain what is the meaning of "not done right". What is the input, output, expected output?

Comment: As you are new for SO, please appreciate the time of other users, so you need at least: properly format your code in your question, explain a concrete issue ('doesn't work correctly' isn't a proper description) with your inputs and outputs.

Comment: I just ran your program and from what you've provided it seems to work fine. Request 3 tickets of type 2 and the total cost was 450. Please go into more details on how this isn't working.

Comment: you should consider to write a function that handles all three cases. The code is identical apart from the variable where you store the price.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize I was not being clear enough, what I meant was, the calculation for individual categories works fine, that is how you got the 450, the problem is after the user buys tickets from a certain category, the question do you want to continue is asked, if 1 (yes) is inputted the program loops back to the category choosing, but when the user enters 2(no), the program is supposed to show the grand total which I declared as total_price. The total_price is supposed to just be the addition of price 1,2, and 3 which I declared.

Comment: Ran out of words, say for example the user buys 3 vip tickets, it shows that its 450, and when asked if they want to continue and the user says no, the grand total is a a huge number (3.54904e+255). The same happens when the user buys tickets from vvip and vip. However, when the user buys at least one ticket from the third option which is the normal tickets, the end calculation is done right. I hope this explains more about my problem.

Comment: I still think the answer is relevant. I also think you should take @tobi303's advice and refactor your code. The sheer amount of lines dealing with output interspersed with logic is going to cause harm at some point...

Comment: @DivaakaranShanmugam the answer addresses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem not to initialize `priceN` (where `N` is one of `1, 2, 3`) variables before calculation of:

```
total_price = price1 + price2 + price3;
```

in case of only one type of the ticket, so the result is unpredictable because variables contain garbage.

You should start with :

```
double price1 = 0;
double price2 = 0;
double price3 = 0;
```

Comment: This worked, thank you I really do appreciate it, I did try to do this actually but without declaring it as a double three times.                                 double type_ticket, num_tickets, price1 = 0, price2 = 0, price3 = 0, total_price, decision;                                                                                 I'm assuming doing it like that won't work?

Comment: Its not the declaration, it is the initialization that is the key here. Multiline declarations are a stylistic choice but the point is there is no default initialization to 0 so you must do it yourself. Sure it will

Comment: So if I added the priceN = 0 at the if else parts, for example in between these two codes,                                                                                     
cout << "\n";
price3 = num_tickets * 100;                                                                  will it still work?                                                                                      
eg                                                                              
cout << "\n";          price3 = 0;
price3 = num_tickets * 100;

Comment: initialize at declaration site for reduced bugs and clearer code.